# How can you stop a Slick Slider animation when a YouTube video starts playing using the Google IFrame Player API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I have a video that is included in my Slick Slider. According to the Slick documentation you need to initialize the slider when the document is ready, however, I am not able to add the Google Youtube Iframe Player API inside of this same document.ready statement. As these two are separated my console warns me that slider cannot be found (variable set to the slick slider). Below is an example of my code. My goal is to turn off the Slick Slider animation when starting the YouTube video and turn on the animation when the YouTube video stops. As it stands on the first video play the slider animation does not end and rotates to the next slide. How can I make the slider stop animating when playing the video but start when stopping the video?

===== JavaScript =====

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var slider =  $('.mainSlider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000
  }); 
 slider.slickPlay();  

  $('.mainSlider').on('beforeChange', function(){
    line.set(0);
    line.animate(1.0); 
  });

 });

/* youtube video in slider */
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    height: '400',
    width: '100%',
    videoId: 'nisAy26sItM',
    events: {
      'onStateChange':onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
  //when the video starts to play move the introduction content down
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if ( event.data == 1)
      {
       //move the introduction content down 
       $('#introContent').animate({top: '0px' }, 500 );
       $('#services').animate({'margin-top': '0px'}, 500); 
       // if you play the video then you need to get rid of bxSlider autoplay
     console.log('pause');
      slider.slickPause();
      }
      if ( event.data == -1 || event.data == 2)
      {
        $('#introContent').animate({top:'-165px'}, 500);
         $('#services').animate({'margin-top': '-100px'}, 500); 
         line.stop();
           $('.mainSlider').slick('slickPlay'); 
      }
      if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
      }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
      player.stopVideo();
    }
  //when the video stops move the introduction content back to were it was
```